# TF400018: Local version table locked

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2012

Got the below in TFS and VS 2012 RC, anyone know of a fix? Doesn't seem to exist on MS website.

> TF400018: The local version table for the local workspace
>   COMPUTERNAME;MYNAME could not be opened. The process cannot access the
>   file because it is being used by another process

Any suggestions welcomed.

Comment: I started having this problem when I tried to be clever and map to a network shared folder (network mapping to W:\)... I was trying to fool TFS into thinking it's a local folder :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We experienced this one as well. Migrating to the RTM makes this happen a lot less, but it can still happen a lot.

When using local workspaces (a new feaure in vs 2012) a local file based database is created to administer changes you make localy. When you change a source file, this file base database needs to be updated. If this update conflicts with the normal update task which routinely checks for changes you get this error. The cause of this issue is usually that you are using local workspace for more items than it was intended or that your disk I/O is too slow.

Workarounds for this are either:

1. Replace your disk with an ssd. Having better I/O makes this issue
   happen a lot less.
2. Switch back to server based workspaces. (which handles this better)
3. Use the TFS-GIT connector and use git for offline support.
4. Split your workspace mapping in portions so they contain less items.

Answer (score 1):

Please delete the files under %Temp% folder and open the project as
 "Run as Administrator " mode .It works for me .

Regards,
Kamaraj

Comment: i clicked up theni i clicked down... meant to click up